How to avoid duplicate notifications when subscribing multiple times to the same Redis channel?
I have an issue where, if I subscribe multiple times to the same Redis channel, my subscribers start receiving duplicate messages.
Here is my subscription method:
public void SubscribeToUserNotifications(string userId, Action<string?> onMessage)
{
    _subscriber.Subscribe
        (
        new RedisChannel($"orders:notifications:user:{userId}",
            RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal), (channel, message) =>
            {
                onMessage(message);
            });
}

I also have a method that publishes a message when a new order is added for a user:
public async Task AddOrderForUserAsync(string userId, OrderInfo order)
{
    var db = _redis.GetDatabase();

    string orderKey = $"orders:user:{userId}";

    string orderData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);

    await db.HashSetAsync(orderKey, order.Id.ToString(), orderData);

    _subscriber.Publish(
        new RedisChannel($"orders:notifications:user:{userId}", RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal),
        orderData
    );
}

I reviewed my code and realized that each time a user subscribes, a new subscription to the same channel is created, which leads to the same message being sent to the same subscriber multiple times.
I tried to check if the subscription already exists, but Redis itself doesn’t seem to provide a direct way to avoid duplicate subscriptions.
I want the subscriber to receive only one notification per published message, even if they subscribe multiple times to the same channel.
Question:
How can I avoid or prevent duplicate notifications when subscribing multiple times to the same Redis channel? Is there a built-in way in Redis to manage this, or should I handle it on the application side?

If you want to implement a message queue, you should take a look at streams.

No built-in way. You could use a flag before subscribe.
bool hasExecuted = false;
public void SubscribeToUserNotifications(string userId, Action<string?> onMessage)
{
    if (!hasExecuted)
    {
        _subscriber.Subscribe(...);
        hasExecuted = true;
    }
}


Issue: How to properly subscribe to Redis Pub/Sub with an asynchronous handler in C#?
If you're trying to use Redis Pub/Sub with StackExchange.Redis in C#, and you want to handle messages asynchronously, you may encounter issues where Subscribe expects a synchronous delegate (Action<RedisChannel, RedisValue>), but your handler is asynchronous.
To solve this, you can wrap your asynchronous logic inside a Task.Run call, which allows you to execute asynchronous code within the synchronous delegate.
Here's how this issue was resolved:
Solution:
Method to add an order and notify subscribers:
public async Task AddOrderForUserAsync(string userId, OrderInfo order)
{
    var db = _redis.GetDatabase();

    string streamKey = $"{_streamKeyPrefix}{userId}";

    string orderData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);

    // Add the order to Redis Stream
    await db.StreamAddAsync(streamKey, new NameValueEntry[]
    {
        new NameValueEntry("orderId", order.Id.ToString()),
        new NameValueEntry("orderData", orderData)
    });

    // Publish a notification to subscribers via Pub/Sub
    _subscriber.Publish(
        new RedisChannel($"orders:notifications:user:{userId}", RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal),
        orderData);
}

Method to subscribe to notifications with asynchronous handling:
public void SubscribeToUserNotifications(string userId, Action<string?> onMessage)
{
    string streamKey = $"{_streamKeyPrefix}{userId}";

    // Subscribe to Pub/Sub notifications for the user's orders
    _subscriber.Subscribe(new RedisChannel($"orders:notifications:user:{userId}", RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal),
    (channel, message) =>
    {
        // Run asynchronous code inside Task.Run
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var db = _redis.GetDatabase();

            // Read messages from Redis Stream within the consumer group
            var entries = await db.StreamReadGroupAsync(streamKey, _groupName, userId, ">", count: 1);

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                // Process the received data
                var orderData = entry.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "orderData").Value;
                onMessage(orderData);

                // Acknowledge the processing of the message
                await db.StreamAcknowledgeAsync(streamKey, _groupName, entry.Id);
            }
        });
    });
}

